# Django generic View for dealing with two forms occur errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

I'm trying to make `django` views for dealing with two forms.
This kind of view is used for 'signup' and 'login' are in same template(For instance, `modal` structure, e.g http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel)

And I got an idea of dealing with two forms from here (https://chriskief.com/2012/12/30/django-class-based-views-with-multiple-forms/)

I have one `model` for user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)


class ChachaUser(AbstractUser):
    birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'birth', 'gender', ]
```

And `form` :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
            years=range(1970, 2015)
        ),
        required=True,
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, initial='M')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('birth', 'gender')
```

I start to implement `view` for `GET` request with this `model` and `form`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from users.forms import MyUserCreationForm
from users.models import ChachaUser


class LoginSignupView(UpdateView):

    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    second_form_class = MyUserCreationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class()
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class()
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(ChachaUser, pk=1)
```

And finally I create `user/login.html` and set url. But it occurs an error when I access it :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 275, in get
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 213, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/Users/Chois/Workspace/django/chacha_dabang/chacha_dabang/users/views/login_signup.py", line 18, in get_context_data
    context = super(LoginSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 122, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 74, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 147, in __init__
    super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

I use `embed()` for debug and realized that `get_object()` occurs error. But I didn't catch what causes the error.

Need your helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an UpdateView, so Django is expecting the main form to be a ModelForm which it will use to display the values from the model instance. You might be able to fix the issue by swapping your main and second form classes.

Comment: By the way, why should I inherit UpdateView? .. I can not understand it.